Ubuntu 22.04 Not Booting After Installation on Lenovo ThinkPad E520
I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my Lenovo ThinkPad E520, but after completing the installation and restarting the laptop, it won't boot into Ubuntu. Instead, it repeatedly enters the boot menu, asking me to select a boot device. When I choose the SSD, it simply returns to the boot menu again.
Here are some details about my setup:

Laptop Model: Lenovo ThinkPad E520
Installation Media: USB stick created with Ventoy and used to install Ubuntu
Storage: 240 GB SSD
RAM: 8 GB
BIOS/UEFI Settings:

I've tried both UEFI and Legacy modes, but the problem persists.
Secure Boot is disabled.


Partitions:

I have a primary Linux filesystem partition (ext4) and a BIOS boot partition.
The disk is GPT partitioned.



Commands and Outputs:
When running fdisk -l, here is the output:
sudo fdisk -l






Disk /dev/sda: 223.57 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk model: VERICO SSD
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F3F2C50A-7042-410C-9F84-105EFDF08978

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048      4095      2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2       4096 468858879 468854784 223.6G Linux filesystem




I've also tried using Boot-Repair, but it didn't resolve the issue. Here is the boot-repair command and some outputs:

sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair

Despite these efforts, Ubuntu still won't boot. Any advice on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it? Could it be related to the way GRUB is installed or an issue with my SSD?

Thanks in advance for your help!








sda is without an EFI partition, but does have a BIOS parition, so looks like a legacy install. The type of install depends upon how the install media boots. The way the install media boots depends upon the machine settings (prefer UEFI over legacy for a UEFI boot) and also upon how the install media is made (the ISO boots both ways, but some tools to make the usb may have options to allow only one type of boot.  I know nothing of Ventoy, but Rufus seems to be highly recommended and can do the UEFI capable boot setup.
